# Amazon RDS instance stopped responding

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, rds

We've been running a large RDS instance in production for over year without a single moment of downtime. Recently, with a bigger budget and higher stakes, we decided to convert it to a multi-AZ instance, to improve reliability and redundancy of our data.

Since then (about two weeks ago), we've had two serious failures of our instance which required rebooting. There is nothing in the 'recent DB events'. There were two DB connection spikes recorded in cloudwatch that occurred at the same time as the failures.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried opening up a ticket with Amazon?  A lot more detail will be necessary to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problems were related to AWS and not to the instance. When this was posted, it turned out to be one of the most serious outages of AWS europe so far.

There are a number of problems with RDS Multi-AZ that mean that it is still possible for automatic failover to not occur, leaving you without a server. Implementers should be aware and build sufficient redundancy into their applications that can mitigate problems in multiple availability zones.